# How to resolve linker errors with Google protobuf from source using MSVC 2015/17 in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, protocol-buffers, linker-errors

In our project, along with our own source files, we have included several protobuf source files directly. They compile fine with g++/clang++ in all the platforms and Mingw in Windows.

Since we want to use [`Qt WebEngine`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtwebengine-index.html), the Mingw is not useful and hence we have to compile our code with MSVC only.

Now while compiling with MSVC (2015/17, 32/64 bit), it gives several linking errors of below nature:

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __thiscall google::protobuf::Message::CheckTypeAndMergeFrom(class google::protobuf::MessageLite const &)" (?CheckTypeAndMergeFrom@Message@protobuf@google@@UAEXABVMessageLite@23@@Z)
>   error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl google::protobuf::internal::ReflectionOps::Merge(class google::protobuf::Message const &,class google::protobuf::Message *)" (?Merge@ReflectionOps@internal@protobuf@google@@SAXABVMessage@34@PAV534@@Z)

**Question**: How to fix all these linker errors?

---

For those who are interested, below are the set of protocol source files, which we include in the .pro file while compilation:

```
external/google/protobuf/any.cc \
external/google/protobuf/any.pb.cc \
external/google/protobuf/api.pb.cc \
external/google/protobuf/arena.cc \
external/google/protobuf/arenastring.cc \
external/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc \
external/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc \
external/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc \
external/google/protobuf/dynamic_message.cc \
external/google/protobuf/duration.pb.cc \
external/google/protobuf/empty.pb.cc \
external/google/protobuf/extension_set.cc \
external/google/protobuf/extension_set_heavy.cc \
external/google/protobuf/field_mask.pb.cc \
external/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.cc \
external/google/protobuf/generated_message_util.cc \
external/google/protobuf/map_field.cc \
external/google/protobuf/message_lite.cc \
external/google/protobuf/reflection_ops.cc \
external/google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc \
external/google/protobuf/source_context.pb.cc \
external/google/protobuf/text_format.cc \
external/google/protobuf/type.pb.cc \
external/google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.cc \
external/google/protobuf/wire_format.cc \
external/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc \
external/google/protobuf/wrappers.pb.cc \
external/google/protobuf/compiler/importer.cc \
external/google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc \
external/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.pb.cc \
external/google/protobuf/compiler/subprocess.cc \
external/google/protobuf/compiler/zip_writer.cc \
external/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc \
external/google/protobuf/io/strtod.cc \
external/google/protobuf/io/tokenizer.cc \
external/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.cc \
external/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.cc \
external/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc \
external/google/protobuf/message_.cc \
external/google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.cc \
external/google/protobuf/stubs/bytestream.cc \
external/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc \
external/google/protobuf/stubs/int128.cc \
external/google/protobuf/stubs/once.cc \
external/google/protobuf/stubs/status.cc \
external/google/protobuf/stubs/statusor.cc \
external/google/protobuf/stubs/stringpiece.cc \
external/google/protobuf/stubs/stringprintf.cc \
external/google/protobuf/stubs/structurally_valid.cc \
external/google/protobuf/stubs/strutil.cc \
external/google/protobuf/stubs/substitute.cc \
external/google/protobuf/stubs/time_.cc \
external/google/protobuf/util/type_resolver_util.cc \
external/google/protobuf/util/internal/datapiece.cc \
external/google/protobuf/util/internal/field_mask_utility.cc \
external/google/protobuf/util/internal/object_writer.cc \
external/google/protobuf/util/internal/proto_writer.cc \
external/google/protobuf/util/internal/protostream_objectsource.cc \
external/google/protobuf/util/internal/protostream_objectwriter.cc \
external/google/protobuf/util/internal/type_info.cc \
external/google/protobuf/util/internal/utility.cc
```

Comment: So it sounds like you're not linking against a protobuf .lib at all, you've just using the files you've included yourself? It sounds like you've got some function declarations in header files that you're now using that you didn't copy across the implementations for. So e.g. try and track down where they're called from and see if MSVC can find the implementations for you in source you've got, or go back to the protobuf you copied from and find the implementations there to copy across.

Comment: @Rup, Actually this Qt code project works perfectly fine with all the other compilation models (i.e. g++, clang++ in Linux, iOS/Mac, Android) and even Windows (with Mingw). The same code has issues in MSVC only. There are 370 linker erros, which are basic building blocks of the protobuf. We haven't changed anything in the code. Has it anything to do with how Qt compiles the code with MSVC? i.e. the only difference here is that there is a folder structure (i.e. `./external/google/protobuf/...`) for all these files. While other source files are in the main folder.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @secavfr, Yes we are able to compile in all the platforms. Don't remember how exactly did we solve. Have you tried latest MSVC?

Answer (score 2):

*Here's a practical view of how I solved the problem, use the same methodology to solve yours.*

Whether it is in your `.pro` file or directly in the `qmake` command, you provide a `LIBS` configuration variable (libraries to be linked to your project).

Here is an example : `LIBS+=-L"c:/vcpkg/packages/openssl-windows_x64-windows/lib" -llibssl -llibcrypto`

To enable this library, you need to provide the `-l` flags after the path. And [as stated in the official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#libs) :

> The library must exist for qmake to find the directory where a `-l` lib is located.

Which means for the example above that the following **files have to exist** :

- `C:/vcpkg/packages/openssl-windows_x64-windows/lib/libssl.lib`
- `C:/vcpkg/packages/openssl-windows_x64-windows/lib/libcrypto.lib`

Make sure they exist.